# Adobe AIR HTML app white screen issue

Tags: javascript, air

I have this issue for a really long time but can't find any solution.

Sometimes the application UI turns white when the app is busy (or maybe the iframe in the app is busy), and it will just happen on some of the computer. (Actually I have never met this situation on my own laptop)

Does any one know why this happen or have the solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Once possible cause could be the fact that Adobe Air is a single threaded environment.

If your application is having to undertake a particularly resource intensive task it will continue until it has finished the job and hence, won't update the UI until after this time often resulting in the appearance of the application 'hanging'.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for your answer and I believe it is running under one thread. What I don't understand is that on my computer, it might be unresponsive, but the UI will still be there, even though frozen. But on some other computer, it just turns white. T-T

Comment: When you say the application is busy, what is it doing? What is the general functionality / purpose of the application?

Comment: Umm, it's a SEO tool. When it's opening a web page in an iframe, the web page might occupy 100% CPU for seconds. But now it turns white when a popup (alert/confirm) shows.